# OnNotifyMessage vs .NET event model

Tags: .net, winapi

Does subclassing .NET WinForms controls with a custom OnNotifyMessage procedure have any advantage compared with regular .NET event handlers, besides capturing additional information?
Does the compiler generate better, faster code using either technique?

Answer (score 1):

It is a substitute for overriding the WndProc() method.  With the "advantage" that OnNotifyMessage() cannot alter the message but WndProc() can.  Note the signatures of both methods, WndProc passes `ref Message msg`, OnNotifyMessage doesn't use `ref`.  WndProc has a CAS demand for SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode, OnNotifyMessage() doesn't.

I never once found a good reason to favor OnNotifyMessage over WndProc.  It is not uncommon to override WndProc because you *want* to alter the message.  Using CAS in a Winforms app is pretty unusual, they almost always run in Full Trust.  And it just stopped mattering all together in .NET 4 with CAS deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes subclassing .NET WinForms controls with a custom OnNotifyMessage procedure is most perfect way , when you use the OnNotifyMessage procedure you are able to access all the messages(events) of your controls .Besides when using the regular .Net event you can only access the events that are supported by the .Net platform.
talking about speed : there is no difference between the two model .
But keep in your mind that using OnNotifyMessage technique is difficult than using regular .Net technique .